# Sql joins from only one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with the design of a query.
I've got one table with alot of rows(it needs to be in one table).

```
Table name: 201201
columns = code, batch, value, volume
rows =    301,  2920,  100,   2000
          301,  3192,  40,    800
          302,  6479,  230,   3100
          303,  4930,  20,    50
          303,  3920,  60,    95
```

How could I pull the results so it's presented in this way:

```
code, batches, value, volume
301,  2,       140,   2800
302,  1,       230,   3100
303,  2,       80,    145
```

I have done this when I use multiplie tables but can't get it to work when all rows are in the same table.

I manage to get the batch count and mrdr with this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`201201`.code), count(DISTINCT(z.batch)) as batches
FROM `201201` 
LEFT JOIN `201201` AS z ON `201201`.code = z.code
GROUP BY `201201`.code
```

But then I'm stuck. 
Thanks in advance.

New issue! 
Okay, so in the same table I have a risk column that contains a float number for each batch:

```
    Table name: 201201
columns = code, batch, value, volume, risk
rows =    301,  2920,  100,   2000,   0.3
          301,  3192,  40,    800,    0.2
          302,  6479,  230,   3100,   0.8
          303,  4930,  20,    50,     0.8
          303,  3920,  60,    95,     1
```

What I would like is to multiply the risk with the value for each row and then sum it per code, like this.

```
code, batches, value, volume, risk
301,  2,       140,   2800,   38
```

Where 38 comes from, 0.3*100 + 0.2*40.
The same for code 302 and 303.

Comment: You should rename your table as well. `201201` is completely ambiguous. Rather give the table a suitable name and add a date field to the table, than giving the table the number of `YYYYMM`

Comment: Hm, does it/could it cause any issues? The thing is that the tables are created by importing excel files ones a month and those files are not containing a date field. So one file = one table.

Comment: No won't cause any issues. You can add the date manually in your SQL, or make the field a `timestamp` and you don't have to do anything, it will autmatically add the timestamp when the row is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to join when you can do this without join? Hope this helps:

```
SELECT `code`, 
        COUNT(`Batch`) as Batches,
        SUM(`Value`) as TotalValue,
        SUM(`Volume`) as TotalVolume,
        SUM(`Value` * `Risk`) as TotalRisk  -- I'm not sure if this works
FROM `201201`
GROUP BY `code`
```

if the above does not work, try Self Join:

```
SELECT a.`code`, 
        COUNT(a.`Batch`) as Batches,
        SUM(a.`Value`) as TotalValue,
        SUM(a.`Volume`) as TotalVolume,
        SUM(b.`SubRisk`) as TotalRisk
FROM `201201` a INNER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT c.`code`, (c.`Value` * c.`Risk`) as SubRisk
                FROM `201201` c
            ) b ON a.`Code` = b.`Code`
GROUP BY `code`
```

Comment: What if I have a column(named risk) that contains a float number for each batch and I would like to do risk*value  for each row and sum the results for each code?

So we have total value and a risk value.

Comment: @Josef is column `risk` located on the same table? Could you update your question so i can work on it. :)

Comment: @Josef I updated my answer. try the first solution and if it fails, try the second one. This is untested.

Comment: Strange, I tried to do something like your first answer before and it did'nt work but when I tried your code it worked! Must haved missed something. Thanks alot john!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are adding up the other values..?

```
SELECT code, count(batch) as batches, sum(value) as values, sum(volume ) as volumes
FROM `201201` 
GROUP BY `201201`.code
```

Comment: Randy, do you know how the query would look like if i would like sum only volumes that comes from distinct batches and codes? The query I have now works greats but only if I have unique numbers...for example if I have code 303 and batch 1 and batch 1 witch volume 20 and volume 30 I would only like to "sum" volume 30 and ignore 20. Now I get 50.

Comment: that is a WHERE clause:  add WHERE batch = 1 or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Code, Count(Batch), Sum(Value), Sum(Count) FROM 201201 GROUP BY Code
```